# Populate controls of dynamically instantiated Page from ASPX file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, webforms, httphandler

Currently I have a single **Example.aspx** file (*with no code behind*) and I want to load it, populate the controls it has, get the ouput of it and do something with it (inside a http handler).

What I am doing is this:

```
// Gets the page and instantiates it?
Type type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType("~/Example.aspx");
Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

// ProcessRequest of page here?

// Error happens here, the page doesn't have any controls (but there is a label).
((Label)page.FindControl("Label")).Text = "Hello World";

using (StringWriter output = new StringWriter())
{
    // Execute the page and output the result into the string writer.
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, output, false);

    // Do something with the output (or save it, email it, etc)
    // ...in this case we render it.
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    context.Response.Write(output.ToString());
}
```

But it doesn't work since the page instance doesn't have any controls (needs to create child controls?).

If I add:

```
page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
```

it works, but I think it runs the whole page life cycle and that includes rendering the page to the response, something I don't want.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? (I ask out of sheer curiosity) Is this just an experiment, or do you have a specific purpose in mind?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732213/284240

Comment: @jwiscarson: This is both an experiment and trying to use asp.net for simple templating. Instead of implementing my own templating system I want asp.net to do it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That method doesn't seem to allow us to populate existing controls in the page with data but thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into [`UserControls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx)? They can be clunky to use sometimes, but it sounds like your goal is similar to their implementation.

Answer (score 1):

When creating page instance with activator, you could hook up with init or load event to execute additional code while proccesing http request. Dont forget it is still an event driven model! I hope it helps.